# How can I print decimal places, up-to the point there are not two repeating zeros?

Tags: java, floating-point, formatting

I would like to change the below output

```
5250.000000000000 
5512.500000000000 
5788.125000000001 
6077.531250000001 
6381.407812500002 
6700.478203125002 
7035.502113281253 
7387.277218945315 
7756.641079892581 
8144.47313388721
```

To the below output.

```
5250.0
5512.5
5788.125
6077.53125
6381.4078125
6700.478203125
7035.50211328125
7387.277218945313
7756.641079892578
8144.473133887207
```

So it appears the logic I need, is to only print decimal places if there is less than two repeating `0` in a decimal place.  I am assuming printf can handle this, but if I really knew, I would not be asking.

Comment: Which data type do you use to represent these decimal numbers in memory? `double`, `float`, `BigDecimal` or `String`?

Comment: Sorry. doubles or floats

Comment: Perhaps you can use regexps (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) to eliminate trailing substrings that follow this pattern: r'0*1?$'. I type this assuming you convert the number to string first.

Comment: Your last 3 lines are inconsistent.

Comment: You will need to use regex

Comment: What if the number has a long serie of 9? For example, the predecessor of 0.1 in double precision 0.09999999999999999167332731531132594682276248931884765625

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either I misread the question or it changed while I was typing, my original answer suggesting DecimalFormat won't do what you're looking for.  Regular expressions will:

```
final String unformatted = Double.toString(6381.407812500002);
final String formatted = unformatted.replaceAll("00+\\d*$", "");
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Yields: `6381.4078125`

You asked for any more than two zeroes and all numbers after them to be replaced, so this matches `00` followed by any digit (doesn't match `.` so this will only trim after the decimal place) and erases it.

---

Original answer:

The answer to practically all your number formatting needs is DecimalFormat (javadoc). Specifically for this case:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.###########");
System.out.println(formatter.format(5788.125000000001));
```

Yields: `5788.125`

In this case I specified up to 11 places of decimals, any more than that will be rounded, and using the `#` (instead of `0` after the decimal place) tells it to not show trailing 0s in that position.

Comment: Your example was almost perfect. We were off by one `5250.0` was printing `5250`.  I changed my code from `NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.###########");` to `NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(".0###########");`and that was the trick. I cannot up vote this but I would if I could. Thank you!

Comment: I've edited NullSoulException's answer implementing the perfect regexp you need. It won't appear until it's peer reviewed. If 1337joe agrees, I'll also suggest him the same pattern edition.

Comment: You suggested `0+[1-9]?$`, which matches zeros followed by a single digit.  The question was "How can I print decimal places ...[without] two repeating zeros?", which makes no mention of only having a single non-zero digit at the end (though that's what the sample numbers had).  My regex will truncate `1.10012` to `1.1` where yours wouldn't match or replace anything.

Comment: `"00\\d*$"` would suffice as regex since 0 is also a digit.

Comment: @1337joe You are right. But why '00+\\d*$' instead of '0+\\d*$' ? (it's curious that Java flavour scapes chars with double backslash... doesn't it?) Well I guess it is to consolidate the long trailing non-zero digits match with at least 2 zeroes...

Comment: Anyways, it is also good to consider my alternative - already peer-reviewed (please check below). It would be more strict than your approach (wouln't match with more than 1 non-zero trailing digit), but interesting in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

One way is by constructing a `regex` that will remove undesired trailing zeros from a given string. Something like the below will do it for you . Just place this  regex inside a loop that is reading your file.

```
  // The 1-9 group would erase the last trailing
  //   non-zero digit, as suggested by the example
  somevariable  = str.replaceAll("0+[1-9]?$", "");
```

Comment: Wouldn't that regexp erase the first digit before the trailing zeros? I'll suggest an edit. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it. I am using double but you can do the same for float as well.

```
double doubleValue = 1001.10210010138200321;
String doubleString = Double.toString(doubleValue);
String[] part = doubleString.split("\\.");
String decimalPart = part[1].substring(0, part[1].indexOf("00"));
String trimmedDoubleString = part[0] + "." + decimalPart;
double trimmedDouble = Double.parseDouble(trimmedDoubleString);
```